# Delete account links from service account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-python-api

We have a service account that has access to data of our different clients' analytics accounts. Apparently there's an undocumented limit of 200 accounts that a specific user (in our case, the service account) can be linked to. This appears when clients try to add our service account address as a user in their accounts.

As we have some old client accounts linked to our service account, we would like to remove their connections to allow new connections to be added.

Using the analytics management API I was able to get the list of the 200 connected accounts. I figured what needs to be done is to delete the `AccounUsertLink` between my service account user and their user. Sadly, as my user has no "user management permissions" on the customer's account, I have no way of finding my user's link id, so I cannot delete the connection.

Is there any other way of deleting connected accounts from my service account user? Thanks